# When mouse hover, the text decoration underline also gets rotated

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10

I have a weird css issue as can be seen here on this jsfiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/4x17wLoj/

```
<ul class="menu">
<li class="hasChildren menuItem">
    <a href="/about-us/our-story.html" class="menuItemLabel">
        Our story
    </a>
</li>
</ul>

.menuItemLabel:before {
   content:"\e008";
   font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
   float: right;
   margin-left: 10px;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
   transform: rotate(0deg);
   transition: .05s;
   font-size: 10px;
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   color: black;
}



  .menuItemLabel:hover:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    text-decoration: none;
   }
```

It worked ok on all browsers. However, on IE10, when I mouseover the underline is shown over the text (And that is ok). However, there is an extra line beside the icon. I think it is because I am rotating the icon using css3. This in turn also rotates the text-underline.

Any help please? I do not want the line beside the icon when hovered. I do want to keep the text decoration underline for the text only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, cross-browser compatibility means trying to deal with IE most of the times, and for your  case, here's the fix, add the following code to your **css**, and have it hovered without the line beneath;

```
li a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: This will also mean I will not have any hover even for the text. I want to keep the text decoration underline for the text only and not for the icon.

Comment: Seems like overflow:hidden does the work. Weird.why?

Comment: Perhaps it finds it overflowing the element box in IE !

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using overflow:hidden as below

```
 .menuItemLabel:hover:before {
     overflow:hidden
 }
```